# Check Constraint based on other column value

Tags: mysql, sql, check-constraints

I have a table named **Table1** with three columns **col1**, **col2**, **col3**.
col1 can have one of the three values(1 or 2 or 3).

I need to add a check constraint such that it checks, if col1 has value 1 then the values of col2 and col3 should be same else if col1 has values 2 or 3, then col2 and col3 values may or may not be same.

Can anyone tell me how to add the constraint for this ?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4):

You can add a check constraint like this:

```
ALTER TABLE Table1 ADD CONSTRAINT chk_table1_cols
    CHECK ( (col1 = 1 AND col2 = col3) OR (col1 IN (2, 3)) );
```

Note that "is the same" presumes that the values are not `NULL`.  That logic can be added, if you want to consider `NULL` values as equal.

Answer (score 0):

You can express these condition with a series of logical operators:

```
(col IN (1, 2, 3)) AND (col2 = col3 OR col1 IN (2, 3)
```

Answer (score 0):

I didn't verify (I don't have MySql) but in Oracle the following works:

```
ALTER TABLE Table1 ADD
(
  CONSTRAINT CHK_1 CHECK ((col1 BETWEEN 1 AND 3) AND (col1 <> 1 OR col2=col3))
)
```

Comment: I can tell you this does not work in MySQL, instead off this you can use a view with check option in MySQL which can do the [same](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/view-check-option.html)

Comment: @RaymondNijland you're probably right (I'm not really familiar with mysql) but https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_check.asp says it should work.

Comment: Wait... MySQL 8.0.16 (Not yet released, General Availability) seams be to going to support it [finally](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/create-table-check-constraints.html) .. For general cases i won't not advice to use w3schools for SQL documentation.